# Best way to fill array from SELECT

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a function to delete a product category from a database. First it SELECTs all child tables that inherit from the table to be deleted from, and will return JSON object of table names if child categories depend on it. What's the most efficient way to fill array with values from SELECT query?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_category(catid INT)
RETURNS json AS $$
DECLARE
    depend "catalog";
    dependlist "catalog"[];
BEGIN
    FOR depend IN SELECT * FROM catalog LOOP
        dependlist:=dependlist || depend;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can use a simple query for that: `select array_agg(depend) from catalog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using append `||` operator is pretty slow way - on some older PostgreSQL versions it is terrible slow. You can use two possibilities - mentioned `array_agg` or `ARRAY(SUBSELECT)` constructor:

```
dependlist := ARRAY(SELECT depend FROM catalog);
```

or

```
dependlist := (SELECT array_agg(depend) FROM catalog);
```

or

```
SELECT array_agg(depend) FROM catalog INTO dependlist;
```

The performance should be same for all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I used the array_agg() function, and this worked fine. Only thing I am unsure of is why I added depend after table name in FROM?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_category(catid INT)
RETURNS jsonb AS $$
DECLARE
    --depend "catalog";
    dependlist "catalog"[];
    cnt INT;
BEGIN
    --Check no other tables dependent 
    SELECT array_agg(depend) INTO dependlist FROM catalog depend
        WHERE inherit_from=catid;
    IF array_length(dependlist,1) IS NOT NULL THEN
        RETURN jsonb_build_object('error',
            'children','tables',to_jsonb(dependlist));
    END IF;
    --Check table is empty of products
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM (SELECT tablename
        FROM catalog WHERE catalogid=catid) AS tname;
    RETURN jsonb_build_object('error','none');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```